# Launch Executable from Secondary thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, ipc, wxwidgets

I need a way to launch executable (process) from secondary thread. The wxWidgets toolkit I use give me no way to the best of my knowledge and now I have to seek platform dependent way (Linux and Windows only) way to do that.

The executable will read and write to the file. Other than knowing that the process is still running or not (and if possible exit code) there is no much this thread is going to do with process itself. After process terminate, the thread will read the written file, analyze it and send result to GUI thread for displaying. I have no idea how to do it since I have been depending on [wxExecute](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__procctrl.html#gaa276e9e676e26bafeec3141b73399b33) all the times.

Comment: Using threads and doing `fork` in Linux is a good way to get VERY confusing results... http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to move quite a few parts of your code from the secondary thread to the main thread. The [wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_process.html) you refer to says it all:

> When a wxProcess object is passed to wxExecute(), its OnTerminate()
>   virtual method is called when the process terminates. This allows the
>   program to be (asynchronously) notified about the process termination
>   and also retrieve its exit status which is unavailable from
>   wxExecute() in the case of asynchronous execution.

And below:

> Currently wxExecute() can only be used from the main thread, calling
>   this function from another thread will result in an assert failure in
>   debug build and won't work.

So, you need to **eliminate the need to call `wxExecute` from the secondary thread**. How exactly you should do this depends on your application, but it will probably involve the secondary thread sending a custom wxWidgets event to the main thread using [`wxQueueEvent`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#gae921d7bd0e52fedbf3f253d2c408bce1). The main thread then handles the event by calling `wxExecute` in asynchronous mode *and* retrieving its result later on.

Now what to do with the result?

Ideally, you rework your application logic such that **the secondary thread does not need the result** but instead:

1. the main thread handles it all by itself, **-or-**
2. *another* secondary thread is started and handles it.

This will minimize the amount of synchronization you have to do, and thus reduce the probability of hard-to-find concurrency programming errors.

Comment: moving wxExecute into main thread will freeze my gui as the operation takes long time to execute and it must be synchronous.

Comment: I don't get it... why can't you call wxExecute with wxEXEC_ASYNC?

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: It will make the call asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want separate processes, or will threads do.

To get separate processes, you need fork() for Linux and CreateProcess() for Windows.  The best approach is often to make a function to encapsulate it.

```
bool RunProces(const std::string &sCmdLine)
{
    #if defined(WIN32)
        // launch with CreateProcess() ...
    #else
        // launch with fork() ...
    #endif
    return bSuccess;
}
```

If, however, you can just use threads, you can use the portable std::thread class.

**An alternative approach** is to use `popen()` (`_popen()` for Windows).  This launches a new process and redirects its output (`stdout`) to a pipe.  You can then read the pipe to retrieve the sub-process output.

A couple of notes about `popen()`:

1. Redirecting the standard output makes it impractical for the sub-process to interact with the user.
2. There would be some overhead setting up the pipe.  Probably not important unless you are spawning large numbers of sub-processes.
3. I've never seen `popen()` used to launch a non-console Windows program (with no `main()` function).  I wouldn't be surprised if there are problems doing that.

Comment: Does create process/fork have any advantage over popen/_popen() proposed here?: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/KadLJ-g4sEU

Comment: Depends on what you want.  popen() writes its output to a pipe that you can then read back.  If that is desirable, then use popen().  If the subprogram needs to interact with the user, I would probably not recommend popen().  Beyond that, both probably work fine.  You might argue that is you don't want the piped output, then avoid the overhead of setting up the pipe -- but the overhead won't be huge.

Comment: No interaction with user whatsoever is needed. I will accept your answer once you add this without deleting the current :) So in Windows its just the same (MinGW and MSVC)?